# How to access JavaScript object other members data whilst iterating over array in handlebars each statement

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a JavaScript object like this

```
 Object {all: Array[5], cattype: "sometype"}
```

My question is, how to write cattype in the code below

I do this

```
 {{#each all}}           
    <li><a href="#{{cattype}}/{{ id }}" >{{{title}}}</a></li>
 {{/each}}
```

This code is working, just cattype is not written. Outside {{#each}} it's working of course.

Thank you very much for your attantion ! :)

Comment: You should post the solution as an actual answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thank you! I'll make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution

```
{{../cattype}}
```

solved my problem